# credited with reviving a lackluster rollout

Tags: word-meaning

> It’s become a standard photo op of the pandemic: leaders rolling up their sleeves for COVID-19 shots to trumpet the advent of vaccines. Israel’s Benjamin Netanyahu was one of the first, Joe Biden did it on live television, while Indian Prime Minister Narendra Modi’s inoculation is being **credited with reviving a lackluster rollout**.

Source: [Fortune](https://fortune.com/2021/03/05/covid-vaccine-has-china-president-xi-jinping-been-vaccinated/)

The word "rollout" in the phrase "credited with reviving a lackluster rollout" appears to have two different meanings to me.
(1) It means the introduction of the vaccine. The problem in my understanding this is that it is collocated with "reviving": The vaccine is new and the introduction is new (because the COVID-19 is new), how can you "revive" it? The best guess I've now got is that there is probably an anti-vaccine movement in India so Modi tries to revive reasonable vaccination. This guess doesn't convince me.
(2) It means the the number of the people who accept vaccination. It is also a guess by me (deduced from voter rollout in American presidential election).

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**rollout**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rollout), noun
>
> 1. An act of rolling out; gradual deployment.
>
> [**roll out**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/roll_out), verb
>
> 1. To deploy or release (a new film or software, etc.); to launch (a product or service), especially in a gradual fashion across multiple regions.

At this point it can hardly be said that the vaccine or its introduction are "new." The various vaccine options *have been being rolled out* for some months now in many parts of the world, including India.

In India this rollout process has (apparently) been described as "lackluster," meaning "not especially notable or significant," in this context meaning "slower than desired." Whether this is because of lack of supply or lack of demand is not made explicitly clear, but because the Prime Minister publicly receiving the vaccine "revived" the rollout, it can be deduced that at least part of the problem was lack of demand.